# How to call models methods from helper function in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I've created a helper file using the following method:

1. Created file in `app/Http/helpers.php`
2. Added file path in `composer.json`
3. Run this command: `composer dumpautoload`

Everything worked well but I want to use my models here so that I don't have to write code for getting data from database every time, but it's giving an error that model class not found.

```
function productImagePath($image_name) {
    $generalSettings = \GeneralSettingsModel::GetGeneralSettings();
    return $generalSettings;
}
```

My requirement is that I want to call some model's functions to get frontend (header/footer) design settings from database. So I've to write that code again and again in each controller. I'm very new in Laravel so if it's not a good approach to use helpers for such things, please guide me how it's possible then.

Comment: What says error you get?

Comment: @piotr Class 'GeneralSettingsModel' not found

Comment: Is the model not in the `App` namespace?

Comment: @RossWilson it is in App namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your `GeneralSettingModel` class is in the `App` namespace you will need to include that:

```
function productImagePath($image_name)
{
    $generalSettings = App\GeneralSettingsModel::GetGeneralSettings();

    return $generalSettings;
}
```

Hope this helps!